# Android Studio automatically starts downloading gradle-3.3-all.zip file from the gradle services and stops when launching a project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When i open a project in android studio in my ubuntu terminal, it automatically starts downloading gradle-3.3-all.zip file from services.gradle.org and hangs my computer. Can someone please solve the issue here it is very important

Comment: please run `df -h` and lets see the result.

Comment: when do i use the df -h command ?

Comment: Open a terminal with `ctrl + alt + t` then type that code and copy and paste in your post

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           386M  6.2M  379M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        33G   20G   12G  64% /
tmpfs           1.9G  740K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           386M     0  386M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           386M   76K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           386M     0  386M   0% /run/user/1
/dev/sda3       246G  202G   44G  83% /media/chintanmehta/12749F32749F1815